# WiFi super slow after 14.04 update on Toshiba Satalite M-55

Tags: wireless, 14.04, lubuntu

I updated my Toshiba Satalite M-55 laptop with Lubuntu 14.04 but after update I have super slow or no WiFi. This is what I have when I type $ iwconfig:

```
iwconfig

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:"gogetter"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 00:25:9C:D9:FC:74   
          Bit Rate=11 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-38 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:3  Invalid misc:169   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

But lspci sees this:

```
lspci

00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RC410 Host Bridge (rev 01)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RC4xx/RS4xx PCI Bridge [int gfx]
00:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RC4xx/RS4xx PCI Express Port 1
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 USB Host Controller (rev 80)
00:13.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 USB Host Controller (rev 80)
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 USB2 Host Controller (rev 80)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 SMBus Controller (rev 81)
00:14.1 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 IDE Controller (rev 80)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 PCI-ISA Bridge (rev 80)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 PCI-PCI Bridge (rev 80)
00:14.5 Multimedia audio controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB400 AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 80)
00:14.6 Modem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB400 AC'97 Modem Controller (rev 80)
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RC410M [Mobility Radeon Xpress 200M]
04:02.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR2413/AR2414 Wireless Network Adapter [AR5005G(S) 802.11bg] (rev 01)
04:04.0 CardBus bridge: ENE Technology Inc CB1410 Cardbus Controller (rev 01)
04:06.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8100/8101L/8139 PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter (rev 10)
```

It was working fine with Zubuntu 12.04. Can you please help? Thanks!

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: This is what came up...

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Sorry...http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7851646/

Comment: The last half of the output is missing? did you enter your password when asked?

Comment: I posted an answer.

Comment: Im sorry, I just noticed your post about half of the output is missing. And no, it did not ask me to log in or a password. What do you suggest I do?

Comment: Nothing, it is fine since your wireless is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do:

```
echo "options ath5k nohwcrypt=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath5k.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv ath5k
sudo modprobe -v ath5k
```

Change the encryption to just wpa2 (CCMP)(AES) not (TKIP) if you have that option it will work best.

Change the channel to 1 or 11 they usually work best.
Save the router configuration, then reboot router  and unplug wired connection.

Set your wireless settings in network manager to match the screenshots.[image: DNS Settings][image: IPV6 Setting]

Then reboot.

Comment: Dude, you did it! Looks like it's working! Thank you so much for your help. You're not just "Wild Man" you're the MAN!!